# Docker Engine Installation failed

Tags: linux, docker, debian, debian-jessie

I have a board with OS Debian 8. And I wanna install "Docker Engine". I have used [this link](http://blog.programster.org/debian-8-install-docker/) for installation, but I got the error message:

[image: img description: Error message]

Do someone have the same? I tried "update", "upgrade" and nothing in the result.

I hope that everything clear, if not sorry, I can give more information.

Best Regards.

Comment: Follow the official guide: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/debian/

Comment: @JazzCat thanks. I tried and the same error.

Comment: If your board's architecture is ARM, you will have to find an installation guide for ARM.

Comment: A few months ago, it was quite straightforward to install docker on a raspberry for example. Just run `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh` as it says [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/docker-comes-to-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: @tgogos I take your recommendation, but it also doesn't work. The same error all the time. On step "setting up..." I received the error, as before.

Comment: Please, don't post picture, copy/paste command and error.

Comment: What does `journalctl -xn` shows?

Comment: @Garf365 Ok, understood.

Comment: @dlmeetei Errors are :Unit docker.service entered failed state.; docker.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.;Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.;Unit docker.service entered failed state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it as describe below:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo rm docker-engine.*
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And that's it...